# How to parse PHP array that has been decoded from JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, loops

I am posting some JSON to a PHP script. I'm doing this through a jQuery ajax call. I think I have the ajax part working well enough. But here's the code I'm using:

```
var testjson = '{"statistics":[{"player_id":"12","team_id":"8","points":"19"},{"player_id":"9","team_id":"8","points":"7"}],"teams":[{"homename":"Lakers","awayname":"Heat","webid":"48","hid":"49","aid":"48"}]}';

function postGameStats() {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ajax-url.php",
    data: {"data":JSON.stringify(testjson)},
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
}
```

On my PHP page, I want to loop through the decoded JSON and store the data in my db. Once I get the values out of the array, I can store them. But I can't get them out of the array at the moment! I can't seem to find an explanation of accessing a multidemensional array in PHP that I can understand. Here's my PHP so far:

```
$finally = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

$size = count($finally[1]);
$i = 0;
while ($i < ($size)) {
  echo $finally[$i].['statistics'].[$i].['player_id']; 
$i = $i + 1;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to access the values from the array? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why are you stringifying a string?

Comment: That's a great point, Musa. Because I wasn't thinking and am just combining stuff from various tutorials I've seen online. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

well you can't access that kind of array when it is **indexed by keys(associative array) and not numbers** so you need to use `foreach()`

```
foreach($myarray as $key => $val){
   echo $key." ".$val['innerkey'];
}
```

so in your case it would be like this

```
   foreach($finally['statistics'] as $key => $val){
      echo $val[$key]['player'];
   }
```

but of course you can use `print_r()` your array so you would know how you will access it

```
print_r($finally);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

the problem with the stringify is the slashes doing the following will solve the issue:

`$finally = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);`

let me know if it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above helped me a great deal. But what ultimately worked is parsing like follows:

```
echo $finally["statistics"][1]["player_id"];
```